# Calculate percentage of declaration from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following fields.

```
 state    plant    edition       declaration   version    date         state_by
 s1      p1        e1               0           1       2019-07-22     null
 s1      p1        e1               1           2       2019-07-22     1
```

Need to calculate `edition wise, declaration=1, max (version) of date wise and state_by=1` data in single query.

Condition for calculate edition %

```
   declaration=1/ declaration  *100
   datewise
   max version
   state_by=1
   edition wise
```

Comment: Desired results would help.

Comment: e1-->80% like this. Want to group by edition with percent

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear, but your title suggests that you are focused on the average of declaration.

You can do that with logic like this:

```
select edition, avg( declaration = 1 ) as avg_1,
       max(version)
from t
group by edition;
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers in a number context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  So, `avg()` returns the proportion of true values.

EDIT:

If you want the percent of edition with `declaration = 1`, then one method is:

```
select count(distinct case when declaration = 1 then edition end) / count(distinct edition)
from t;
```

Comment: Out of total data want to percent of edition which have declaration = 1,  datewise max version data

Comment: Need to select on max version data. How can do it?